# twig loop divisible by apply new class

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following loop which uses divisible by to create a new carousel item.
How can i change the loop to apply carousel-item active only to the first group then apply only carousel-item to the rest of the groups?

```
  {% for item in article %} {% if loop.index % 3 == 1 %}
<div class="carousel-item active">
  {% endif %}
  <div class="card ml-3">
    <div class="card-block">
      <div class="card-title">
        {{ item .title }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% if (loop.index % 3 == 0 or loop.last) %}
</div>
{% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems the solution was pretty simple but didn't notice from the first half on hour spend on this.

```
 {% for item in article %} {% if loop.index % 3 == 1 %} {% if loop.first %}
<div class="carousel-item active">
  {% else %}
  <div class="carousel-item">
    {% endif %} {% endif %}
    <div class="card ml-3">
      <div class="card-block">
        <div class="card-title">
          {{ item.title }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% if (loop.index % 3 == 0 or loop.last) %}
  </div>
  {% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

DarkBee suggested to change this line

```
 {% if loop.index % 3 == 1 %} {% if loop.first %}
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      {% else %}
      <div class="carousel-item">
        {% endif %} {% endif %}
```

to

```
{% if loop.index % 3 == 1 %}
    <div class="carousel-item{% if loop.first %} active{% endif %}">
{% endif %}
```

Which is much better.

Comment: Another solution was doing this `<div class="carousel-item{% if loop.first %} active{% endif %}">`, saves you the extra div there